# What is is called when you repeatedly press strings on a guitar and strum at the same time?

Tags: guitar, technique

What is is called when you repeatedly press strings on a guitar and strum at the same time? If you do it fast enough on an acoustic guitar it will make a wah-wah-wah-wah sound. This is without a pedal, or a whammy bar. It probably is basically "bending" the pitch but going downwards instead of sideways. If you do it slower it will essentially make a staccato sound because the fingers mute the strings when you are not pressing on them as hard.

Anyway, I'm guessing it has a name if every single chord has a name, there must be a name for this as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you play, or have access to an example on you tube please post a video or link.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. I'm thinking possibly there are two things going on. It is repeated left hand muting and unmuting very quickly. Along with very hard strumming. Perhaps it is a combination of "overdriving the top" which begins to distort the sound along with the repeated muting to distort it more. Edit: Oh yes and that momentary tiny pitch bend that probably naturally happens between muting and unmuting.